# Can I show that a positive power of $2$ plus a perfect square is not divisible by $7$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I've gotten another proof down to just having to prove that a positive power of $2$ plus a perfect square is not divisible by $7$:

$$7\nmid(2^k + n^2), \; k,n \in \mathbb{N}$$

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit:

Note that
$$2^k \pmod{7} \in \{1,2,4\}$$

$$n^2 \pmod{7} \in \{0,1,2, 4 \}$$

We have listed the values that $2^k \pmod7$
 can take, we just have to make sure that the values that $−2^k \pmod7$
 can take is not in those values that $n^2 \pmod7 $
 can take. For example, $1$
 is a value that $2^k \pmod7$ can attain, $−1 \equiv 6 \pmod7$
 is not a value that $n^2 \pmod7$  can take.

---

Remark:

The original question was $7 \not\mid 2k+n^2$.

You can't since it is not true.

$$1^2+2(3)=7$$

A general strategy to get more counterexamples is choose any $n$, note the parity of $n$.  find $l$ such that $7l > n^2$ where $l$ and $n$ share the same parity. $7l-n^2$ is a positive even number.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even realize. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Ahh, I just realized where I went wrong. 2k in my proof should be 2^m. I have edited the question.

Comment: But wouldn't n^2 (mod 7) be congruent to 1,2,4 as well since n is a natural number. I'd gotten that far, I just don't know how to turn that into a proof.

Comment: We have listed the values that $2^k \pmod{7}$ can take, we just have to make sure that the values that $-2^k \pmod{7}$ can take is not in those values that $n^2 \pmod{7}$ can take. For example, $1$ is a value that $2^k \pmod{7}$ can attain, $-1 \equiv 6 \pmod{7}$ is not a value that $n^2 \pmod{7}$ can take.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That makes sense.

Comment: This seems to be answering an earlier version of the question, which is confusing... sure, questions shouldn't generally be edited to change their meaning substantially, but now that it's happened, could something be done to bring the question and answer in sync? Whether that should be editing the answer, deleting it, rolling back the question, or something else, I don't know.